# Error with Python Sympy computing integral for the area of a circle

Tags: python, typeerror, sympy, symbolic-integration

I am using iSympy to computing integral of area of a circle, but keep getting "TypeError: symbolic boolean expression has no truth value."

```
In [2]: x, y, r = symbols('x, y, r')

In [3]: integrate(sqrt(r**2 - x**2), (x, -r, r))
```

the Error:

```
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\relational.pyc in __nonzero__(self)
109
110     def __nonzero__(self):
--> 111         raise TypeError("symbolic boolean expression has no truth value.")
112
113     __bool__ = __nonzero__

TypeError: symbolic boolean expression has no truth value.
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Your code works for me in SymPy Live (http://live.sympy.org/). Maybe you are using a different version of SymPy.

Comment: yes, the version I'm using is SymPy 0.7.5 (Python 2.7.6-32-bit), are there differences on the way using function integrate()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in SymPy, which will be fixed in the next version.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of SymPy you will not obtain an integrated result unless you make the 'r' variable positive

```
>>> var('r',positive=1)
r
>>> integrate(sqrt(r**2 - x**2), (x, -r, r))
pi*r**2/2
```

Notice that you get the area of a half-circle, too. Compare to

```
>>> Circle((x,y),r).area
pi*r**2
```